# Similar selects, how to know which one is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where rows can be added which include drop downs (select) fields.  each one of those fields is dynamically created with an id of "drop1, drop2, drop3" etc.

I'm wanting to achieve pulling some data from mysql with ajax, problem i'm having is knowing which drop down has changed to pull the data.

ive used this to know how many select fields there are currently, but don't know how to decide which one has changed.  any help is appreciated.

```
var myCount = $("select[id^=drop]").length;
```

here is the row that gets added.

```
var n=($('.detail tr').length-0)+1;  

var tr = '<tr>'+  
'<td>'+n+'</td>'+
'<td><select id="drop'+n+'" name="prodService[]"></select></td>'+
'<td id="desc'+n+'"></td>'+ 
'<td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a></td>'+ 
'</tr>';
```

Comment: please add select code

Comment: Why do you need a count?  Your event handler should have the target in context

Comment: If you attach an event handler to the selector, like `.change( function() { ... } )`, you can use `$(this)` inside of the function to refer to the element that's changing.

Comment: updated to show the code that adds a row with the select info

Comment: the reason i'm wanting it is each row will have a drop down and when it is changed, a service is selected for that row, i am going to call for the description of that service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea around the `select input` it's like any input accepts all events. Any input takes `click`, `change`, `input`...etc let's say we have 3 select dropdown.

How to detect if any of them has changed and get the new value

```
$('.select-list').on('change', function(evt) {
    console.log($(this).val());   // get the select value - new value if changed
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));   // just for implementation purposes and debugging   
});
```

Going further you can implement something like: When the user selects an item from a dropdown, send a request to a server to get some data. You can do that with the `value=""` attribute, put keyword/key-trigger (just to differentiate between them) to send different request depending on what item has been selected.

```js
$('.select-list').on('change', function(evt) {
  console.log($(this).val());   // get the select value - new value if changed
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));   // just for implementation purposes and debugging   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-list" name="items" id="itemsList1">
     <option value="1">item1</option>
     <option value="2">item2</option>
     <option value="3">item3</option>
     <option value="4">item4</option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="select-list" name="items" id="itemsList2">
     <option value="1">item1</option>
     <option value="2">item2</option>
     <option value="3">item3</option>
     <option value="4">item4</option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="select-list" name="items" id="itemsList3">
     <option value="1">item1</option>
     <option value="2">item2</option>
     <option value="3">item3</option>
     <option value="4">item4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: thank you.  in my head i was making it way more difficult that it had to be!

Comment: ok so i'm using your suggestion, it works, but only on the first select input that is not created with javascript.  i'm just printing to the console and if i add another row with javascript the row shows up but when i change the select input it does not print to the console.  any ideas?

Comment: i used var t = $(".select-service").length; and printed t to the console and its counting them correctly

Comment: when i use this -- $.each($(".select-service"), function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).val());
  
 });   it prints the correct stuff.  

this is my code for the event handler - 
     $(".select-service").on('change', function(evt) {
  console.log($(this).val());   // get the select value - new value if changed
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));   // just for implementation purposes and debugging   
 });